# Is it possible to have the select element's dropdown to always appears downwards?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to force the `<select>` element's dropdown box to always display values downwards? The user needs to see the data in the form above while selecting from dropdown.

Comment: So in some cases a web browser may render a drop-down box so that  it's options are displayed above the HTML select entity, thereby hiding some important information, right?

Comment: @maerics: exactly the user needs to see the above info for selecting the right one from dropdown, as dropdown contains lots of information it prevents the user from seeing it...thanks for the reply

Comment: You are not making yourself clear here. Ar you using a `<select>` element, or creating your own replacement for that, or using something else entirely? Regardless of all that, posting some code/images of what you want will help us immensely here.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really control the direction a drop-down is opened (unless you replace it with a JavaScript control), but you can display a `<select>` element as a list by setting its `size` attribute:

```
<select size="6">
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option>Saab</option>
  <option>Mercedes</option>
  <option>Audi</option>
</select>
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/ugulu4

Comment: I am not clear with "unless you replace it with a JavaScript control"...please explain how to make it possible with a simple example...